# Yii2 modal with composite key

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, yii2, composite-key

Can anyone help me with the composite key? I am not able to function properly.

```
function init_click_handlers(){
  $(".button-endereco").click(function(e) {
            var fcodigo = $(this).closest("tr").data("codigo");
            var fcodigopessoa = $(this).closest("tr").data("codigopessoa");
            var map = {codigo: $(this).closest("tr").data("codigo"), codigopessoa: $(this).closest("tr").data("codigopessoa")};
            $.get(
                "update ",
                {
                    codigo: fcodigo
                    codigopessoa: fcodigopessoa
                },
                function (data)
                {
                    $("#endereco-modal").find(".modal-body").html(data);
                    $(".modal-body").html(data);
                    $("#endereco-modal").modal("show");
                }
            );
        });

}

init_click_handlers(); //first run
$("#endereco_id").on("pjax:success", function() {
  init_click_handlers(); //reactivate links in grid after pjax update
});

$url = Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('../endereco/update?codigo='.$dataProvider->codigo.'&codigopessoa='.$dataProvider->codigopessoa);
```

Comment: Could you further explain how it's not functioning properly?

Comment: With the script this way, the form appears mangled and google chrome on the way to inspect accuses error in javascript. But if I put a comma after the code: fcodigo to give error, but the _form appears blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you want refer to the data inside a $dataProvider you firts need to get the model you need. In dataProvider all the models relate to your query are available and you can get from the models  array  the specific model accessing by the a proper index eg:

```
myModel = $dataProvider->models[yourIndex]

myValue = myModel->myField
```

In your case foe example you could get the vaue in this way

```
myModel = $dataProvider->models[0]:
myValue = myModel->codigo;
```

Comment: They are two models I need, I'm actually trying to use a modal _form with a composite key.
Until you get there that way, but of a script error and interferes in other modules as in kartik.

Answer (score 0):

I got 90% of the response, but could not catch my composite key (password, codigopessoa), forced the values to test the function and it worked.
So lack I get the column values (composite key).

```
function init_click_handlers(){
  $(".button-endereco").click(function(e) {
             fcodigo = $(this).closest("tr").data("codigo");
             fcodigopessoa = $(this).closest("tr").data("codigopessoa");
             $.ajax({
                url: "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('endereco/update').'",
                type: "GET",
                data: {"codigo": parseInt(17), "codigopessoa":parseInt(8)},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                        $("#endereco-modal").find(".modal-body").html(data);
                        $(".modal-body").html(data);
                        $("#endereco-modal").modal("show");
                }
            }); 
        });
}

init_click_handlers(); //first run
$("#endereco_id").on("pjax:success", function() {
  init_click_handlers(); //reactivate links in grid after pjax update
});
```

Comment: data: {"codigo": parseInt(fcodigo), "codigopessoa":parseInt(fcodigopessoa)},
RESULT: GET http://sistema.iprem.com/endereco/update?codigo=NaN&codigopessoa=NaN 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

[100% working] Finally got it, for those who want to use the Gridview (kartik) with composite key follows the code:

```
function init_click_handlers(){
  $(".button-endereco").click(function(e) {
             chave = $(this).closest("tr").data("key");
             $.ajax({
                url: "'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('endereco/update').'",
                type: "GET",
                data: {"codigo": parseInt(chave["codigo"]), "codigopessoa":parseInt(chave["codigopessoa"])},
                //data: {keylist: parseInt(keys)},
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data) {
                        $("#endereco-modal").find(".modal-body").html(data);
                        $(".modal-body").html(data);
                        $("#endereco-modal").modal("show");
                }
            }); 
        });
}

init_click_handlers(); //first run
$("#endereco_id").on("pjax:success", function() {
  init_click_handlers(); //reactivate links in grid after pjax update
});
```